# How to define private repo image in Gitlab Runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, amazon-ecr

I have a gitlab runner register with `docker+machine` executor and I have setup my `.gitlab-ci.yml' as below:

```
stages:
  - RUN_TESTS
  - CLEAN

image:
  name: <AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.<AWS_REGION>.amazonaws.com/<NAMESPACE>:<TAG>
```

And the image `<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.<AWS_REGION>.amazonaws.com/<NAMESPACE>:<TAG>` is a private `AWS` ECR repository. And It fails everytime as this is a private repository.

How can I configure this to pull this private image?

I got the password of the ecr using `aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2` command and it gave an password.

I looked into this `docker-credential-ecr-login` tool and installed this in runner instance. And I configured the AWS credentials using `aws configure` and credentials are now at `~/.aws/credentials`

And also add the following block to `~/.docker/config.json` as below:

```
"credHelpers": {
        "<aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com": "ecr-login"
    }
```

But when I try to `docker pull  <AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.<AWS_REGION>.amazonaws.com/<NAMESPACE>:<TAG>` it gives me the following error:

> Error response from daemon: Get https://Account-ID.dkr.ecr.REGION.amazonaws.com/v2/spot-runner-image/manifests/latest: no basic auth credentials

Is there anything to do with `docker-credential-ecr-login`

Answer (score 4):

You're getting that error because your runner (and/or the job) isn't authenticating with the ECR registry before it tries to pull an image. You'll need to provide the auth data in one of the following forms:

- a `$DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` variable in the job (see the docs for info: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#create-a-custom-variable-in-gitlab-ciyml)
- a `$DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` project variable from your project's **Settings -> CI/CD** page (see the docs here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#create-a-custom-variable-in-the-ui)
- a `$DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` variable in your runners `config.toml` file (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#configuring-a-runner)

The docs on setting the `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` are here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-an-image-from-a-private-container-registry.

To determine what should be in the `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` variable, you can log into your registry from your local machine with `docker login example-registry.example.com --username my_user --password my_password`. This will create a `config.json` file in the `~/.docker` directory. However, on my mac the credentials are stored in my keychain, and the config.json file can't be used by Gitlab. In that case, you'll have to create the content manually. All this information and more is in the docs: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#determining-your-docker_auth_config-data